# casting apr_time_t to different int types

Tags: c, casting, apr

```
gcc 4.7.2
c89
APR 1.4
```

Hello,

I am compiling my program in 32 bit mode i.e. `-m32` as some of the libraries I am linking with use 32 bit libraries.

I have the following structure:

```
struct tag_channel {
    apr_int32_t id;
    char *name;
};
```

For the id I want to have a random number so I am using the APR:

```
apr_time_t time_secs = apr_time_sec(apr_time_now());
```

I am wondering about casting because apr_time_sec returns an apr_time_t type which is:

```
typedef apr_int64_t
```

I could cast into the following:

```
channel->id = (apr_int32_t)time_secs;
```

However, I am worried about the loss of value by casting down.

The following is 64bit, so not sure if this would work.

```
#define APR_TIME_T_FMT   APR_INT64_T_FMT
```

I don't want to change the channel structure for the id to `apr_time_t` as it doesn't really make sense to have time value for an ID value.

Which is the best way to cast this?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `apr_time_usec` for desired random number. apr_time_usec seems to be "more random", because it returns usecond part (the whole time is `sec + APR_USEC_PER_SEC * usec`) and is guaranteed to be inside `[0 .. 1000000]` by definition, so you may don't worry about loosing precision with cast.

If using seconds, not useconds is crucial, then you may calculate your random number as

```
channel->id = (apr_int32_t) (apr_time_sec(apr_time_now()) % INT32_MAX)
```

(don't forget to include `limits.h`) to fit it inside 32-bit diapason some smarter then just by truncation.